# Why do I get an Invalid Argument when using the removeLabel function in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I'd like to remove my user created label called "Add-to-Spendee-2", from a collection of emails. I've pretty much followed [Google's removeLabel() Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label.html#removeFromThread(GmailThread)) to the dot on this, but I keep getting an **"Invalid argument: label"** error.

Here's the code:

```js
function removeLabel()

{
  var myLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('test-add-to-spendee-2');
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:test-add-to-spendee-2 AND from:swiggy AND subject:(Your receipt for Swiggy order)");

  for (var x in threads) 
  {
  var thread = threads[x]
  thread.removeLabel(myLabel)
  }
  
}
```

**Note: If I substitute the `removeLabel(myLabel)` with any other function like `markUnread()`, the code works perfectly.**

Comment: I just did that recently and I found that the description of the label in the gmail search window did not agree with how I actually created the label.  It display  a  label like this `q0-subject-name` and I had it created as `Q0/Subject/Name` when I used `q0-subject-name` I couldn't find the  label and when I used `Q0/Subject/Name` I found it.  I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code will work but I think all you need to do is:

```
var lbl=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Q0/Subject/Name');
var threads=GmailApp.search('label:Q0/Subject/Name');//exactly as you created it
lbl.removeFromThreads(threads);
```

Try using the debugger and make sure that threads is getting an array of GmailThread objects.

[image]

This is what the label look like in the Gmail search window:

[image]

They changed the slashes to dashes and used lower case and that's not really what the label looks like.

As I said above in  my comment:

I just did that recently and I found that the description of the label in the gmail search window did not agree with how I actually created the label. It displayed a label like this `q0-subject-name` and I had it created as `Q0/Subject/Name` when I used `q0-subject-name` I couldn't find the label and when I used `Q0/Subject/Name` I found it.

Comment: So, definitively, does scripts need to use formulation with slashes or dashes? I have a label "comms" inside "earnings", and have tried "earnings-comms", as per search. It may be working, but I'm not sure, as I'm getting some "Invalid arguments".